# Python Tornado - TCPServer and Application

Tags: python, routes, tornado, tcpserver

I set up a tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer which uses H2, to get HTTP2 working.
Now i face following issue: I can't create routes and it looks like there's no way to bind Tornado.web with Tornado.tcpserver...

AFAIK tornado.web.Application works only with tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer :/
But Tornado still doesn't support HTTP2, so using tornado.httpserver is absolutely a no-go from me -_-

Does anyone know a workaround or function which allows us to bind tornado.web.Application with tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tornado.web.Application` implements the [`HTTPServerConnectionDelegate`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerConnectionDelegate) interface. To use it from another server, call `start_request` and pass the http headers and other data from your server implementation to the returned `HTTPMessageDelegate`.

There's also a native tornado implementation of HTTP/2 in https://github.com/bdarnell/tornado_http2

Comment: Awesome implementation! Thanks alot